# onclick event show the calendar for the previous image

Tags: jquery

is this code is ok

This is a part of code

```
create_table.find("#f_trigger_c").each(function(){
            var oclk = " displayCalendar(document.prjectFrm['"+ ia +"dtSubDate'],'yyyy-mm-dd', this)";
            var newclick = new Function(oclk);
            jq(this).click(newclick);
      });
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an improvement:

```
create_table.find("#f_trigger_c").each(function() {
    jq(this).click(function() {
        displayCalendar(document.prjectFrm[ia + "dtSubDate"], 'yyyy-mm-dd', this);
    });
});
```

When possible, you should declare a function:

> Function objects created with the Function constructor are parsed when the function is created. This is less efficient than declaring a function and calling it within your code, because functions declared with the function statement are parsed with the rest of the code.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function